# Combining gulp-crisper with gulp-webpack

Tags: javascript, polymer, gulp, webpack

I'm setting up my environment to develop a polymer 1.0 application using ES6/babel.

I also want to integrate webpack, so that I can use `import` statements in my javascript code.

I use gulp as a build tool. This is a (simplified) gulpfile for my project:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var crisper = require('gulp-crisper');
var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(gulpif('*.html', crisper()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', webpack({
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/],
                    loader: 'babel-loader?sourceMap=true'
                }
            ]
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This works if I use gulp-babel instead of gulp-webpack. But so I get the following error:

```
[10:28:38] Using gulpfile E:\Dokumente\polymer\test-gulp-webpack\gulpfile.js
[10:28:38] Starting 'default'...
[10:28:38] Finished 'default' after 225 ms
[10:28:38] Version: webpack 1.12.2

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' E:\Dokumente\polymer\test-gulp-webpack\src\index.js in E:\Dokumente\polymer\test-gulp-webpack
```

The `src` directory contains only a `index.html` with the following content:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <script>
            var test = "TEST";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion how I can fix this? Maybe tell crisper to temporarily write the javascript to the filesystem? Or maybe use some fancy loader for webpack?

Comment: in the example above, it looks like you're sourcing only html files into the gulp stream.  not sure what gulpif is doing, but it looks like you are expecting a .js file in the pipeline and not getting one.  You should be able to stick with the gulp-webpack, but webpack will need some sort of entry file.  in this case there may be none.  can you simplify a bit?

Comment: crisper generates a js stream by extracting the script tags from the html file. As I wrote, this works with gulp-babel. Only webpack seems to have a problem with it.

Comment: gotcha, I think I know what the problem is. if index.html only has a script tag with that one variable, its likely that webpack is expecting an entry file object, not a buffer, so you need to convert that buffer into a vinyl source stream.

Comment: I realize this is old, but I'm trying to do the same thing and this post keeps coming up. The issue I'm having is that Webpack is trying to look for the file on the hard disk instead of using the gulp stream. @Giacomod'Antonio were you able to get it working?